# Is there a firefox add-on/chrome extension that will enlarge Gmail compose area?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, gmail, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a firefox add-on/chrome extension that will enlarge Gmail compose area?

When I'm on my laptop, half of the Gmail compose window is occupied the TO:, CC:, and the subject, so there is only small space available for the actual writing area. Even when you write a lengthy email, the writing box doesn't enlarge, so you can only scroll within the small writing area, not the entire page.

Is there any way (through firefox add-on or chrome extension maybe) that can solve this problem? If either the writing box can be enlarged or the To:, CC:, subject hidden after they are entered (a la iPad), it would really make Gmail writing experience more efficient.

Comment: Ok, this is definitely not a good solution. But if desperate, try  http://m.gmail.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this [userstyle](http://userstyles.org/styles/27916/bigger-gmail-compose-box-tested-2010-05-04) helps (to be used with [Stylish for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome) or [for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/stylish)).

The [Bigger Gmail Compose Box](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2009/11/26/bigger-gmail-compose-box/) Chrome extension also seems to be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While checking out the userstyle for Firefox, I discovered that resizing the compose box in Gmail is now native to Firefox. You don't need any third-party add-on. You still need third-party extension for Chrome though to be able to resize the gmail compose box.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down either the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and click *Compose* to compose a new Gmail message in a new web browser tab. The new Compose screen is full height and ~90% full width in my web browser. The part of the new tab that has the compose workspace in it has a 5% margin on both sides, right and left, however the new compose tab is full screen. These two margins might be a feature to make Gmail easier to use for people who are used to working with other email clients that have an additional navigation pane on the left side and the new message pane does not extend to 100% of the width of the screen.

I thought the 90% width of the Compose workspace might have something to do with *Keyboard shortcuts* in Gmail Settings, but it works the same way with *Keyboard shortcuts off* and *Keyboard shortcuts on*.